# Editing offsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

I have a savegame. Into offset 1FCC0 bytes C-D-E is stored the game money. So I'm making a script to open the file, setting C-D-E to FF (The max) and save the file (or copy it and modify the copy).

That's the code I have but I don't know how to continue:

```
#import os when its finished to make it beautiful
#import time when its finished to make it beautiful (with sleeps times :D)
import tkinter
import binascii

#Preguntamos al usuario por el archivo a abrir y lo guardamos en la variable filename
filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

#Abrimos el archivo de origen (filename)
lector = open(filename, 'rb')

#Almacenamos el contenido (lo leemos) en una variable
contenido = lector.read()

#Cerramos el archivo porque ya lo tenemos en una variable
lector.close()

offsetdec = ("1FCC0H")

input()
```

PS: Some TAB spaces or something are not working well I'm IDLE for me
My version is 3.4.2

Anyone can help me about finishing it?

Comment: Please learn `open`, `file.seek` and `file.write`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the indentation of this! Sorry bud!